# Tkinter opens unwanted new window with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I try to make a download interface via tkinter. The following code works well in Pycharm. But when I try to make it an exe file using pyinstaller, it opens a new window every time I click on button1(the download button), which is undesired. Could you please tell me how to fix it? I'm working on Win10. Thanks in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from download import download_yv as dyv
import multiprocessing

class DownloadPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid()
        self.download_flag=True
        self.current_row=0
        self.current_rowspan=0

        self.label1=tk.Label(self,text='Url:',)
        self.label1.grid(row=self.current_row,column=0,)

        self.text1=tk.Entry(self,width=45)
        self.text1.grid(row=self.current_row,column=1,padx=0,pady=0)

        self.current_row+=1
        self.label2=tk.Label(self,text='Save_Dir:',wraplength=200,)
        self.label2.grid(row=self.current_row,column=0)

        self.text2=tk.Entry(self,width=45)
        self.text2.grid(row=self.current_row,column=1,padx=0,pady=0,)

        self.current_row+=1
        self.label3=tk.Label(self,text='Overwrite:',)
        self.label3.grid(row=self.current_row,column=0)

        self.var1=tk.BooleanVar(self)
        self.var1.set('False')
        self.menu1=tk.OptionMenu(self,self.var1,'True','False')
        self.current_rowspan=2
        self.menu1.grid(row=self.current_row,column=1,columnspan=2,rowspan=self.current_rowspan,sticky='news')

        self.current_row+=self.current_rowspan
        self.label4=tk.Label(self,text='Categorize:')
        self.label4.grid(row=self.current_row,column=0)

        self.var2 = tk.BooleanVar(self)
        self.var2.set(True)
        self.menu2=tk.OptionMenu(self,self.var2,'True','False')
        self.menu2.grid(row=self.current_row,column=1,columnspan=2,rowspan=self.current_rowspan,sticky='news')

        self.current_row+=self.current_rowspan
        self.current_rowspan=2
        self.button1=tk.Button(self,text='download',command=self.download)
        self.button1.grid(row=self.current_row,column=1,columnspan=2,rowspan=self.current_rowspan,sticky='news')

        self.current_row+=self.current_rowspan
        self.button2=tk.Button(self,text='Stop Downloading',command=self.stop_download)
        self.button2.grid(row=self.current_row,column=1,columnspan=1,)

    def download(self):
        var1=self.var1.get()
        var2=self.var2.get()
        # print(var1,type(var1),var2,type(var2))
        self.download_process=multiprocessing.Process(target=dyv,args=(self.text1.get(),self.text2.get(),var1,var2))
        self.download_process.start()


    def stop_download(self):

        if self.download_process and self.download_process.is_alive():
            self.download_process.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=tk.Tk()
    app=DownloadPage(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to show us the `.spec` file you made for `pyinstaller`. The Python code doesn’t tell us anything useful about the problem you describe.

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ss0435QHuMpMIdQ9q6PYeBKG2NtrC8v9/view?usp=sharing
Thanks